# Picture box not drawing right on some computers

Tags: grid, size

I am making a math game and it involves making a graph. On some computers it works perfect but on some the graph does not match the picture box. It doesn't have to do with screen resolution as I have tried changing that with no difference. Any ideas on why it does not draw the same on every computer?

This is the code that draws the grid.

```
private void PaintGrid()
    {
        for (int i=1;i<20;i++) { 
          // Draw grid rectangle into the buffer
          using (Graphics bufferGrph = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
          {

            bufferGrph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray, 2), i * 30, 1, i * 30, 600);
            bufferGrph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray, 2), 1, i * 30, 600,i * 30);
          }
        }
        using (Graphics bufferGrph = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
        {
            bufferGrph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.CadetBlue, 5), 300, 1, 300, 600);
            bufferGrph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.CadetBlue, 5), 1, 300, 600, 300);
        }

        // Invalidate the panel. This will lead to a call of 'panel1_Paint'
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
```